# formvalidation.utils.fetch ver los errores de php

Tags: php

Estoy utilizando formValidation.js de https://formvalidation.io/
para validar un formulario y enviarlo a php

```
FormValidation.utils.fetch(RP_AJAX_CTR+'u_crud.ajax.php',
{
    method: 'POST',
    params: objectifyForm(data_i),

}).then((response)=>
{
    console.log(response);
    if(response.result === 'register_success')
    {
    //redirectTime(rutaOcultaPHP+'register-success', 0.1);
    }
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error.response.data.message)
})
```

Hasta aquí todo bien, el problema viene cuando hay algún tipo de error en el archivo php el cual ya no devuelve el mensaje en formato json.
Entonces lo que recibo es un mensaje de error así:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Mi pregunta es cómo puedo hacer para ver en cuál línea es que el archivo php está dando dicho error, algo como así:

> Fatal error: in u_crud.ajax.php on line *34*

Para poder ir a la línea y arreglar ese error. Espero poder darme a entender.

Comment: En realidad el error no te lo va a marcar en PHP, sino en JS. Tenés que ver qué te está devolviendo el _response_.

Comment: Creo que el problema, según el error, no está en el archivo php sino en el diccionario o "json" que estás pasando. En este caso, es porque en json todos los nombres de claves deben ir entre comillas, es decir, tendrías que tener:
{'method': 'POST', 'params': objectifyForm(data_i)}
Además de que en un diccionario, las últimas claves no deben tener una coma al final

Answer (score 0):

en el catch puedes usar la error mensaje para tener mas detalles

```
.catch(function(error) {
                    console.log(error.message)
                })
```

y siempre puedes usar las herramientas de desarrollador de tu navegador (F12) en red o network para poder ver la respuesta a tu peticion http, realizada por el fetch